# Evaluate the integral $\int_0^1 e^{-x^{4}}(1-x^{4}) dx $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

How to find the definite integral of  $$\int_0^1 e^{-x^{4}}(1-x^{4})dx $$ I tried solving this by using integration by parts and then by substitution but want able to solve this by either of those methods .

Comment: Substitute x^4=t

Comment: @Heonji Ha I've tried that . It didn't help me at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said, there is not elementary solution.

However, you can use series expansions to get, for example, $$e^{-x^{4}}(1-x^{4})=1-2 x^4+\frac{3 x^8}{2}-\frac{2 x^{12}}{3}+\frac{5
   x^{16}}{24}-\frac{x^{20}}{20}+O\left(x^{22}\right)$$ and integrate each term.

Let us call $J_n$ the value of the integral up to $O\left(x^{4n+1}\right)$. In this case, you would obtain the following values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & J_n & \approx \\
 1 & \frac{3}{5} & 0.600000 \\
 2 & \frac{23}{30} & 0.766667 \\
 3 & \frac{93}{130} & 0.715385 \\
 4 & \frac{19297}{26520} & 0.727640 \\
 5 & \frac{44879}{61880} & 0.725259 \\
 6 & \frac{20206379}{27846000} & 0.725647 \\
 7 & \frac{195313597}{269178000} & 0.725593 \\
 8 & \frac{2455393823}{3383952000} & 0.725599
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

What is good using Yves Daoust's answer is that we can *a priori* know how many terms have to be added in the expansion for a given number $p$ of accurate digits for the final result.

Since the series ia alternating, the remainder is smaller that the first negelected term. So, if we add $n$ terms the remainder if such that $$R_n=\frac 1 {(4n+5)(n+1)!}$$ what we want to be smaller than $10^{-p}$. This write $${(4n+5)(n+1)!}>10^{p}$$ and a rough approximation gives $$n=2.33676 \,p^{0.724341}-1.70173$$

Comment: Hi Claude. Integrating by parts, you can get rid ot the $x^4$ term, which simplifies the process a little.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Perfectly correct (once more !). This starts to be tiring !! (joke). Cheers.

Comment: sorry, I cannot work without simplifying things first, so that I can understand them ;-)

Answer (score 3):

this integral can not expressed by the known elementary functions.
the result is given by $$\frac{4+3 e \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-3 e \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4},1\right)}{16 e}
$$

Comment: I am feeling confused here . I can't understand any of this and is that result a. Definite value ?

Comment: $$\Gamma$$ is the so called gamma function

Comment: So there is no other way to calculate the integral ??

Comment: Any other way either leads to the same answer or is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

By parts,

$$\int x^4e^{-x^4}dx=-\frac x4e^{-x^4}+\frac14\int e^{-x^4}dx$$ and on both terms you are left with

$$\int_0^1 e^{-x^4}dx$$ for which there is no analytical antiderivative.

It requires the incomplete Gamma function, or can be evaluated by the fast converging series

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(4k+1)k!}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=x^{4}$
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{1} \mathrm{e}^{-x^{4}} dx = \frac{1}{4} \int\limits_{0}^{1} \mathrm{e}^{-y} y^{-3/4} dy
= \frac{1}{4} \gamma\left(\frac{1}{4},1 \right)
\end{equation}

Using the same substitution, we also have
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{1} \mathrm{e}^{-x^{4}} x^{4} dx = \frac{1}{4} \int\limits_{0}^{1} \mathrm{e}^{-y} y^{1/4} dy
= \frac{1}{4} \gamma\left(\frac{5}{4},1 \right)
\end{equation}

Thus we obtain
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{1} \mathrm{e}^{-x^{4}} (1-x^{4}) dx
= \frac{1}{4} \Big[ \gamma\left(\frac{1}{4},1 \right) - \gamma\left(\frac{5}{4},1 \right) \Big]
\approx 0.7256
\end{equation}

We have used the [lower incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function):
\begin{equation}
\gamma(s,z) = \int\limits_{0}^{z} \mathrm{e}^{-x} x^{s-1} dx
\end{equation}